# Custom UIButtons

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, uibutton

I need to implement a view with clickable areas just like HTML image maps. The background of the view will be an image that fills the entire canvas and the boundaries of each clickable area are different is size and shape. What is the best scenario to do this in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use invisible buttons.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can bind actions to views as easily as to buttons, so you can just add a bunch of views as you like, then set the actions that you like in Interface Builder.